# Update of column values on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wanted to update the column values on satisfying condition. I wanted the values to `1,2,3,4,5,...`

I tried this query but its behaving in a strange way. I'm getting the values starting from `2` i.e `2,3,4,5,..`

```
declare @id int;

set @id = 0;

UPDATE table 
SET id = @id + 1, @id = @id + 1
WHERE col4 = 100
  AND col5 = 500
  AND col3 = 2
```

Comment: Please provide table definitions, sample data, and expected output: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you're receiving an error message or behavior that you don't expect, please provide details on that as well.

Comment: look to ROWNUMBER() or a numbers table

Comment: Your query looks like a MySQL query, not a SQL Server query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you want to enumerate records that meet the criteria specified in the `WHERE` clause. I would suggest using a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
  SELECT id, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col3) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  WHERE col4=100 AND col5=500 AND col3=2
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET id = rn
```

Comment: @J19 The problem with your query is that `@id` is *first* set and *then* read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Declare @id int;
Set @id=1;

UPDATE table 
SET @id = id = @id + 1
WHERE 
(col4=100 AND col5=500 AND col3=2)
```